# How to do an ascending order of a folder's items stored in a list with python?

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains some xml files. I'm trying to read those files and store it in a list in ascending order. I have written the following codes, nonetheless, I'm not sure how to do it. The folder contains files such as:

a.xml_1

a.xml_2

a.xml_3

...

When I run the following codes, the created list is not ordered.

```
import os

path = 'mypath/folder/'

xml_files=[]
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files:
    xml_files=[f]
    print(xml_files)
```

Comment: Well. You've not tried to order it, so why would you expect it to be? Investigate sorting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this one, it will give you all the files sorted in ascending order in a single list**

```
import os

path = 'mypath/folder/'

xml_files=[]
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files:
    xml_files.append(f)
xml_files.sort()
print(xml_files)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I sort like this, after ```xml_1``` it gives ```xml_10``` and then goes to ```xml_11```

Comment: So, ```xml_2``` happens after ```xml_19```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

print (sorted(os.listdir('./')))
```

You can also use `glob` btw:

```
import glob

print (sorted(glob.glob('./*')))
```

You may have troubles if you wish to sort alphanumerical strings. There is a famous function for that:

```
import re

def sorted_nicely( l ): 
    """ Sort the given iterable in the way that humans expect.""" 
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text 
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)
```

You can then use:

```
 print (sorted_nicely(os.listdir('./')))
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I sort like this, after ```xml_1``` it gives ```xml_10``` and then goes to ```xml_11```.  Also, ```xml_2``` happens after ```xml_19```.

Comment: For that you need to use the sorted_nicely function I suggested.